# How can I draw a route between two geopoints on the Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can I draw a route between two geopoints on the Flutter with the new widget Google Maps? There were some tutorials about how to do this with the previous widget, but now it's deprecated.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried tutorias like this: https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/08/flutter-how-can-draw-route-on-google.html

But it's deprecated...

I'm looking for tutorials or examples that show how to do this with the new widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of implementing it. This is how I did it few weeks ago. First i had these plugins:

```java
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
```

next create your GoogleMap object:

```java
LatLng izp = LatLng(-3.386943, 29.371636);

  GoogleMap googleMap = GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: izp, zoom: 10.0),
      compassEnabled: true,
      scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
      onMapCreated: (g) {
        gmc = g;//for mapcontroller if any
      },
      markers: {},
      polylines: {},//initialize the polylines list
    );
```

From Google Directions, fetch directions between your two points. 
Decode the result and get points. should be at this position:

```java
dynamic directions = decodedResult["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]['points'];
```

Create a PolylinePoints object and decode your directions object:

```java
PolylinePoints points = new PolylinePoints();

List<PointLatLng> result = points.decodePolyline(directions);
```

Create a list of `LatLng` from the list of `PointLatLng`:

```java
List<LatLng> po = [];
      result.forEach((f) {
        po.add(LatLng(f.latitude, f.longitude));
      });
```

Then with that list of `LatLng`, create a polyline object:

```java
 Polyline route = new Polyline(
          polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
          geodesic: true,
          points: po,
          width: 20,
          color: Colors.blue);
```

Then after set the polyline object to the your google map object:

```java
 setState(() {
 //if you created markers, add them too if you wish
        googleMap.markers.add(marker);
        googleMap.markers.add(marker2);
        googleMap.polylines.add(route);

        /*if you associated a googlemapcontroller, you can do further actions like zooming...*/
      });
```

I think this should help. Good luck

Comment: I got an error in that line: 

`dynamic directions = decodedResult["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]['points'];`
&nbsp;
The error is: 
&nbsp;
Undefined name 'decodedResult'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifier).

Comment: That's just an example, when implementing, remember to decode your json result into a map

Comment: Oh, ok. I understood it. Thank you!